# How to prevent duplicate tasks when run same IScheduledExecutorService on apps in cluster?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to understand difference between hazelcast methods for  IScheduledExecutorService  for prevent duplicate tasks.
I have two java app with HazelcastInstance. Respectively I have hazelcast cluster with two HazelcastInstances (servers).
I use IMap and want to reset AtomicLong every midnight.

```
    config.getScheduledExecutorConfig("my scheduler")
            .setPoolSize(16)
            .setCapacity(100)
            .setDurability(1);


class DelayedResetTask implements Runnable, HazelcastInstanceAware, Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = -7588380448693010399L;

    private transient HazelcastInstance client;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final IMap<Long, AtomicLong> map = client.getMap(HazelcastConfiguration.mapName);

        final ILogger logger = client.getLoggingService().getLogger(HazelcastInstance.class);
        logger.info("Show data in cache before reset: " + map.entrySet());
        map.keySet().forEach(key -> map.put(key, new AtomicLong(0)));
        logger.info("Data was reseted: " + map.entrySet());
    }

    @Override
    public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) { this.client = hazelcastInstance; }
}

private void resetAtMidnight() {
    final Long midnight = LocalDateTime.now().until(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DelayedResetTask(), midnight, TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(1), TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

I don't want to execute this task on each instance in parallel. After reading documentation [documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/scheduledexecutor/IScheduledExecutorService.html) I don't understand how I can execute reset in both servers for one step (without duplicate tasks, without execution on both servers at one time).
What method I can use for my task `scheduleOnAllMembersAtFixedRate` or `scheduleAtFixedRate` or `scheduleOnMembersAtFixedRate`.
How to prevent duplicate tasks when run same IScheduledExecutorService on apps in cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your code only once in the cluster, since the map you are resetting can be accessed from any member. Both members access to the same map instance, only the entries are kept in different members. You can use `scheduleAtFixedRate` to run it once.

Additionally, you do not need to call `IMap#keySet().forEach()` to traverse over all entries in the map. Instead, you can use `EntryProcessor` as below:

```
    public static class DelayedResetTask implements Runnable, HazelcastInstanceAware, Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = -7588380448693010399L;

    private transient HazelcastInstance client;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final IMap<Long, AtomicLong> map = client.getMap(HazelcastConfiguration.mapName);

        final ILogger logger = client.getLoggingService().getLogger(HazelcastInstance.class);
        logger.info("Show data in cache before reset: " + map.entrySet());
        map.executeOnEntries(new AbstractEntryProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Object process(Map.Entry entry) {
                entry.setValue(new AtomicLong(0));
                return null;
            }
        });
        logger.info("Data was reseted: " + map.entrySet());
    }

    @Override
    public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) { this.client = hazelcastInstance; }
```

Comment: it's some kind of mistake, but with in this case I had a duplicate. In first application data reseted in correct time (I started it first), but in second application data reseted twice not in correct time (after 6 houres). I see log 'Show data in cache before reset:' in both servers. I think this is mistake, but don't understand why,

Comment: Have you scheduled it only once? If you scheduled the job each time you've started the application, than it will run twice. Can you please confirm that you schedule only once?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. I have two jar (application) with same code (you saw it in question). I run they (applications) in different servers in different time. Each application start job with IScheduledExecutorService (startRequestCounterScheduler()).

Comment: Both of your applications will build a cluster when they are running at the same time. You need to call `executor.scheduleAtFixedRate` API only once in a single cluster (from only one of your applications), since it will schedule another job each time you call it.

Comment: @ Alparslan Avci thank you for answers. I have same code in my applications and I don't want to choose a leader or in program case to choose what a node will start IExecutorService. I saw in docs Scheduled Executor Service what the name of the task allows to prevent duplicate tasks.executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(named("my tasks", new DelayedResetTask()), 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES); Will this solution help for me in my case?

Comment: yes, the `NamedTask` will guarantee that the task will be scheduled *at most once*.